# Richtextbox drag drop different than form drag drop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop, richtextbox

so I have a richtextbox and a form, and have attached a drag enter and drop event to them. The code for both of them are EXACTLY the same, I've made sure of it, but for some reason, the richtextbox event activates the Text Changed event. The form would activate the text changed event aswell, but I have a variable in the method that I call from the drag event that blocks it. I've tried to reproduce it on a different form, but the main kicker is that the code for the forms drag and drop events are EXACTLY the same as the richtextbox drag drop events. How could they possibly be different? Here is the drop drop code:

```
    private void TestBox_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
                    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            }
    private async void TestBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
            {
                string filePath = ((string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop))[0];
                await AsyncStuff();
            }
    private async Task AsyncStuff() 
    {
        block = true;
        await OtherAsyncMethodThatActivatesTextChanged();
        block = false;
    }
        private bool block;
        private void TestBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            if (block) return;
            MessageBox.Show("Text Changed called"); //Activates on the richtextbox drag, doesn't on the form
        }
```

I am able to reproduce it now, here is the code. I attached the form drag drop and enter events through the designer.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            richTextBox1.AllowDrop = true;
            richTextBox1.TextChanged += TestBox_TextChanged;
            richTextBox1.DragDrop += TestBox_DragDrop;
            richTextBox1.DragEnter += TestBox_DragEnter;
            AllowDrop = true;
        }
        private void TestBox_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
        private async void TestBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            string filePath = ((string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop))[0];
            await AsyncStuff();
        }
        private async Task AsyncStuff()
        {
            block = true;
            richTextBox1.AppendText("asd");
            block = false;
        }
        private bool block;
        private void TestBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (block) return;
            MessageBox.Show("Text Changed called"); //Activates on the richtextbox drag, doesn't on the form
        }

        private async void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            string filePath = ((string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop))[0];
            await AsyncStuff();
        }

        private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
    }
```